# What does this strange symbol ":>" in bash mean

Tags: bash

I found something in a script, but not belonging to the main script. There was **`:>`** in a line.

Could you explain to me what it means?

```
:> file
while read A B C D E; do echo "$A;$B;$D;$E;$C" >> file; done < otherfile
```

Comment: Importantly, `:>` is not a single operator. It may be easier to understand if you read it as `: > file` instead.

Comment: It means that the person writing the script should have redirected the output of the loop to the file: `while read A B C D E; do echo "$A;$B;$D;$E;$C"; done < otherfile > file`. Or better yet, they should have used the right tool for the job, awk, [as suggested by Peter](http://superuser.com/a/966266/385589). As an aside, [you almost always want to use the `-r` switch with `read`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read#read_without_-r).

Comment: Outside bash, it would be a smiley for a crow.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

#### There was :> in a line of a bash script. What does it mean?

```
:> file
```

It is a short cut way of saying:

- If `file` does not exist then create it else truncate it to `0` bytes.

This means you can be sure that `file` exists and it is empty.

You can also use `> file` but `:> file` is more portable.

See the Stack Overflow question [What Is the Purpose of the ':' (colon) GNU Bash Builtin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin) for more information.

Comment: I don't understand second line. I thought, that read read variables. Command echo is strange too. Could you explain?

Comment: I'm not a Unix expert but I think the second line reads things from `otherfile` and `echo`s them out to `file`. It also makes variables from whatever it reads... If you want a definite answer please ask your own question.

Comment: @diego9403: `read` gets input from stdin. On its own, it would read what you type. Since stdin have been redirected to `<otherfile` then the contents of `otherfile` is "typed" into stdin. So `read` gets the values line-by-line into the variables $A, $B, $C, $D and $E.

Comment: So it is just a more obscure alternative to [`truncate`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/truncate-invocation.html#truncate-invocation) from coreutils?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni It would appear so. Maybe it is faster as `:` is a shell built-in?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: `:>` is a common enough idiom for truncating files to zero.  You only need coreutils `truncate` if you want to truncate to a different length.  `:` is another name for `true`, and both are shell built-ins.  The OP should have asked this on unix.SE.

Comment: @PeterCordes I didn't mean "obscure" as in "it's uncommon", but as in "it's less clear to the reader".

Comment: @PeterCordes I was only answering the `:>` question which was explicitly asked. You make some good comments and I think they are worth a separate answer which concentrates on reviewing what is wrong with `while read A B C D E; do echo "$A;$B;$D;$E;$C" >> file; done < otherfile`

Comment: @DavidPostill: Yup, moved my comments into an answer.  I kinda got carried away replying to the OPs comment (which could have been a new question, or an edit to the question).  I still should have just made an answer instead of replying to that comment.

Answer (score 29):

It looks like a fancy way of creating a new file. In `bash` `:` is a null command:

```
$ type : 
: is a shell builtin 
$ help : 
:: :
    Null command.

    No effect; the command does nothing.

    Exit Status:
    Always succeeds.
```

`>` redirects output of `:` to a file.

Comment: It will also truncate the file if it already exists ...

Comment: yes, this is what `>` does

Comment: `:` is shorthand for `true`.  Possibly in in some shells, `true` isn't a builtin?  Both are built-ins in bash.

Answer (score 12):

`:` is another name for `true`.  Both are shell builtins in bash, but there's no `/bin/:`, only a `/bin/true`.  Output redirection causes the shell to `open(2)` the file with `O_CREAT|O_TRUNC`.  If nothing is written, it stays at zero length.

Putting those two pieces together, `:> file` is a fairly common idiom for truncating files.  Most people would try to make it less weird-looking by writing `: >file`, though.

---

Since you asked in a comment about the 2nd line, I'll turn my comments into an answer.  (even though you didn't ask this in your question.)

The 2nd line is a loop that reads lines from `otherfile` into some named variables.  The loop body uses `echo` to print them with `;` separators instead of whatever whitespace they had before.  `file` is closed and re-opened (for append) each iteration, because the redirect is inside the loop. Using `while ...;do read -r ...;done <otherfile >file` would suck less, and avoid the need to truncate file first. `read -r` doesn't eat `\` as an escape character.

Text processing in bash is quite slow.  Part of that is unavoidable: `read` has to go one byte at a time (one `read(2)` system call per byte) to avoid overshooting the end of a line.  It would be better to use the right tool for the job:

```
awk -vOFS=';' '{ print $1, $2, $4, $5, $3 }' -- otherfile  >file
```

`--` means your script doesn't break if `otherfile` is named something silly like `--version`.

Setting the Output Field Separator to `;` means you can just pass multiple fields as args to print.  Shell `read` assigns the whole rest of the line with whitespace to the last variable, but there's no way to tell awk to only split into 5.  If that's important, maybe just keep using a bash loop, because it's inconvenient in awk.  Perl makes this easy, since its `split` can take a max-fields arg, but it's a lot slower to start up than awk.

Actually, it turned out to be not that hard, just an ugly regex to write.  To get rest-of-the-line instead of `$5` in awk, looping over fields still loses their original whitespace.  My first viable idea is to use `gensub` on `$0` (the whole line) to remove the first 4 fields (i.e. non-space followed by space), leaving everything else:

```
awk -vOFS=';' '{ tail = gensub("[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){4}", "", 1); print $1, $2, $4, tail, $3 }' -- otherfile >file
```

I got it right on the first try, but the fact that I was impressed with myself for that says something about the readability of that awk code. >.<

Note how it's the same `print` as before, but with `tail` in place of `$5`.

```
echo 'A  B c DD    e      f g    f' | 
  awk -vOFS=\; '{ tail = gensub("[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){4}", "", 1);
   print $1, $2, $4, tail, $3 }'

A;B;DD;e       f g    f;c
```

This would be more impressive if I could copy/paste the literal  and show that it came through in the output.  Type one in bash with ^Q.  ctrl-Q means Quote the next keypress as a literal character, since bash's emacs-style line editing is the same as actual emacs for this.

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ has some useful stuff about scripting in ways that won't break no matter what data or filenames you throw at the script.